# running firebase transaction within ArrayAdapter and getView

Tags: transactions, firebase, android-arrayadapter

Could you run a firebase transaction within an Array adapter and getView as this ;

```
      public class upImgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public List<uploadedContentModels> upImgModelsList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public upImgAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                        List<uploadedContentModels> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        upImgModelsList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    /** getting the view ref. to be implemented in the listview & declaring layout elements **/

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        }

        /** passing the image to the UIL **/

        ImageView imageViewDisplayMemebers;
        imageViewDisplayMemebers = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDisplayMemebers);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(upImgModelsList.get(position).getAddress(), imageViewDisplayMemebers);
       final String imgToBeRatedRef = upImgModelsList.get(position).getPublic_id();

        RatingBar ratingBar;
        ratingBar = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                newRatingImg = (ratingBar.getRating());
            }
        });

        Button buttonRatingSubm;
        buttonRatingSubm = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRatingSubm);
        buttonRatingSubm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final Firebase firebaseRefRating = new Firebase("https://cloudname.firebaseio.com//data/images/" + imgToBeRatedRef + "/rating");
                firebaseRefRating.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        int currentRating = (int) mutableData.getValue();
                        int updatedRating = (currentRating + newRatingImg);
                        mutableData.setValue(updatedRating);

                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

            return convertView;
```

the problem i am facing that when i run the debug and after i clikc the button, i see that the execution jumps from the address line

```
   public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
```

to the end of the getView method ( after return convertView )
i've tried several ways, by passing a method inside the click listener ( i.e submitRating(); ) and created that method passing the same code in it, and the same behavior happened, i also tried to use setValue without the transaction, and also the same thing went on !?

could someone explain this behavior to me, is it because of the Array Adapter and the get view or something wrong with my code that i could not spot !?

```
                  public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
               ratingNew[0] = (ratingBar.getRating());
            }
        });

        Button buttonRatingSubm;
        buttonRatingSubm = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRatingSubm);
        buttonRatingSubm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.e("myTag","Before doTransaction()");

                final Firebase firebaseRefRating = new Firebase("https://wi4x4.firebaseio.com//data/images");
                firebaseRefRating.child(imgToBeRatedRef).child("rating").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        Log.e("myTag","Inside doTransaction()");

                        int currentRating = (int) mutableData.getValue();
                        int updatedRating = (currentRating + ratingNew[0]);
                        mutableData.setValue(updatedRating);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "submitting rating"
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(firebaseError != null){
                            Log.e("myTag","After doTransaction()");

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Rating Submitted"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Log.e("myTag","Error doTransaction()");

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error submitting rating failed"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many operations in Firebase (and the modern web in general), the transaction handler is being invoked asynchronously. You can easily see this by adding a few log statements:

```
final Firebase firebaseRefRating = new Firebase("https://cloudname.firebaseio.com//data/images/" + imgToBeRatedRef + "/rating");
System.out.println("Before runTransaction()");
firebaseRefRating.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        System.out.println("Inside doTransaction()");
        int currentRating = (int) mutableData.getValue();
        int updatedRating = (currentRating + newRatingImg);
        mutableData.setValue(updatedRating);

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }
});
System.out.println("After runTransaction()");
```

Unlike what you may expect, the output will be:

> Before runTransaction()
>
> After runTransaction()
>
> Inside doTransaction()

The reason for that is that to run a transaction the Firebase client may need to call to it server to get the current value at the location. This is an asynchronous operation. To prevent blocking the program, the client continues with the next statement *after* the `runTransaction()` call. Then when the client has determined the current value, it calls your callback.

Comment: good tip using log to follow up the steps of the execution, but even though i did apply it, as you could see in the updated post, i get the Toast of a successful subm. but no changes in the nod accrue ? the value did not change, i made sure that the variables "imgToBeRatedRef" & "newRating" are not null in the debug, but with no changes to the nod ?

Comment: Replace the toasts with regular log statements, capture the relevant output and post that. That saves you from having to describe toasts or post screenshots of text.